# How do I create a flag when fallback link was executed in requireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have this piece of code:

```
var skin = "christmas";

    requirejs.config({

    paths: {
        languagesLocal : [
            BaseUrl +  skin + '/js/languagesLocal',
            BaseUrl +  "default" + '/js/languagesLocal'

        ]
    }
});
```

I want to have a variable that tells me which link was executed.

something like `isFallbackLinkWasExecuted == true`

How can I achieve that? or execute a code incase the fallback link was triggered.

Comment: Did you check my updated answer in [http://stackoverflow.com/a/13973183/1916258](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13973183/1916258)? Or is it not related?

Comment: This is not related. I have tried your answer from the previous post and it didn't work for me. I guess I need to do more research about that requireJS to understand your solution because I thought there is an easier solution.